# Do you know any easy way to use javascript game engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, game-engine

For a school development project I need to create a bomberman-like game in javascript which will feature a person vs person online gaming.
I can use any open-source library/framework I want.

The thing is that javascript is a pretty hard language to learn from scratch and I probably won't be able to do it in time.
For know I only know ruby on rails witch I'll be using for the backend, save, rooting, etc...

So I went looking for a really easy and fast to use game engine in javascript.
I already found some pretty popular ones like Gamejs, box2dweb or tapjs even a full list at https://gist.github.com/768272 but I'm unable to choose any of them.

Which one provide the best tutorials, documentation, etc...

Any help would be welcome... As you can see, I'm total newbie in game development.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/), it's a nice and easy to use Javascript game library.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from these two videos from Google I/O

[GRITS: PVP Gaming with HTML5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Prkyd5n0P7k)

[Gaming in the Cloud](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lMcNPDR6uw)

They give you a pretty descriptive walkthrough of how they made an entire game using HTML5 and Javascript. it's pretty in-depth but I highly recommend watching it. They also open source the game which you can fork on Github if you want to see the source etc. This isn't a javascript framework though but it does teach you a lot of how to make an HTML5 game from SCRATCH.

In terms of libraries, yes [Box2d](http://sourceforge.net/projects/box2d-js/) is a very good one and is pretty widely known. Idk if you're trying to make a 3D game but if you are, [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) was something that caught my eye (it was used to make this HTML5 racing game called [HexGL](http://hexgl.bkcore.com/)). Finally I would also recommend taking a look at [Ludei](http://ludei.com/) because they have some really great demos which you can kinda just copy and paste. They also help you if you want to move your game onto the mobile space.

Based on what you said though, I would stick with Box2d. I'll try to find some good tutorials and I might update my answer later with more libraries/tutorials if I find any. Hope for the best!